# What can I do with all these items I pick up?

Tags: yakuza-3

I haven't been playing Yakuza 3 for too long, and already I have come across a wide variety of completely unrelated and seemingly useless items.

There are of course items with very clear use, such as weapons and health increasing items, but also: A coral reef, a broken watch, a multi-purpose thumbtack, a nail made out of platinum, a squishy ball and a myriad of other nonsensical things.

Do all of these items serve some purpose? If not, can I perhaps sell them somewhere, or do something entirely different with them that I am yet unaware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've been able to tell some you can just sell (Gold/Platinum Plates, for example), but a large number can be used to create weapon modifications.

I've personally found that Yen was never an issue (normal playthrough), and your hideout can stock seemingly unlimited quantities of items, so if I were you I'd just put everything in stock (save healing items, of course) until the end game.

(Some story missions, as well as side stories, also require certain items, so if you find them that saves a bit of Yen. Tuna and Catnip sticks, for example.)